# Only show an element when it's inside another element

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a box and two elements that would slide in upon click, switching one for the other, but I want them only to be visible inside the box.

Here's my lousy, stupid, stinkin' code, please assist.

**HTML**

```
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">
  <button>switch</button>
</label>
<div id="box" style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-size: 18px;">
  <div id="slider">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="t2"><a id="s2" href="https://soundcloud.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">Soundcloud</a></td>
        <td id="t2"><a id="s2" href="https://mixcloud.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">Mixcloud</a></td>
        <td id="t2"><a id="s2" href="bandcamp.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">Bandcamp</a></td>
        <td id="t2"><a id="s2" href="https://hearthis.at" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">Hearthis.at</a></td>
        <td id="t2"><a id="s2" href="https://archive.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="slider2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="t2">1111111111111</td>
        <td id="t2">222222</td>
        <td id="t2">333333</td>
        <td id="t2">4444444444</td>
        <td id="t2">5555555</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS.

```
#box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solixyzd #ccc;
}
#slider {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
}
#toggle {
    position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#toggle + label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#slider2 {
  margin-top: -100px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
}
#toggle:checked ~ #box > #slider {
  margin-top: -80px;
}
#toggle:checked ~ #box > #slider2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/pen/xdeevd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding overflow:hidden to the box should work.

```
#box {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a parent and child class, Child for default is hidden. Like this example.

Css :

```
.child{display:none}
.parent .child{ display:block }
```

Html :

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"> Visible Division </div>
</div>
<div class="child">Hidden Division</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You hide your in such a way that, its not working.

So change below CSS it will work

```
#toggle {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0; 
}
#toggle:checked ~ #box > #slider2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}
#toggle:checked ~ #box > #slider{
    display: none;
}
```

Rest you can use your own idea for more animation and yes click on left corner 
so that checkbox work or you can google for hiding checkbox at the same time make it work.

Thanks,
Debashis